# remove object property in nested json by map javascript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I'm trying to remove a property colorIds from my total json response.

```
    const catalog = (materials) => (finishes) => (colors) =>
      materials.map((material) => ({
        ...material,
        finishes: finishes

          .filter((finish) => {
            const materialId = finish.materialId;
            delete finish.materialId;
            return materialId == material.id;
          })
          .map((finish) => ({
            ...finish,
            colors: colors.filter((color, i) => {
              const colorIds = finish.colorIds[i];

              return colorIds.includes(color._id);
            }),
          })),
      }));
```

each finish has `materialId` and `colorIds` which we don't want so I'm currently deleting the finish.materialId after it's been filtered. I'm trying to do the same for the `colorIds` as well but it seems that it's needed in the `colors` inner `filter()`.

I was wondering if there's a way to over come I tried adding subsequent `map`s to no avail.

Comment: Can you please add example input and expected output to your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
const removeKeys = (obj, keys) => obj !== Object(obj)
      ? obj
      : Array.isArray(obj)
      ? obj.map((item) => removeKeys(item, keys))
      : Object.keys(obj)
          .filter((k) => !keys.includes(k))
          .reduce(
            (acc, x) => Object.assign(acc, { [x]: removeKeys(obj[x], keys) }),
            {}
          )
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.